# why _FEATURES_H can be used to check if a header is the first included header

Tags: c++

I happen to read this code:

```
#if defined( _SYS_FEATURE_TESTS_H) || defined(_FEATURES_H)
#error "You should include config.h as your first include file"
#endif
```

The result is `#include <config.h>` must be the frist header file to be included. Why it works like this? what is macro `_FEATURES_H`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic here.

> why `_FEATURES_H` can be used to check if a header is the first included header

It can't be used for this.

This code tests if some **specific** header (preusmably called `features.h` or similar) is already included. It works based on the assumption that the header being detect defines this macro. If a header doesn't define any macros it can't be detected in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Both `_SYS_FEATURE_TESTS_H` and `_FEATURES_H` are [*header guards*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include).

`_SYS_FEATURE_TESTS_H` is defined in `sys/features.h` when that is included. `_FEATURES_H` is defined in `features.h` when that is included.

In the implmentation you use, both `sys/feature_tests.h` and `features.h` are affected by the macro definitions made in `config.h` so `config.h` checks that it's included before the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Based on its usage, we can deduce that `_FEATURES_H` is a pre processor macro. Based on its naming, we can guess that the macro is probably used as a header guard possibly for some header provided by the language implementation. Based on the error message, we can guess that `config.h` probably includes those headers and thus lack of header guard would imply that `config.h` hasn't been included.

Since some of this relies on guessing, it may be a bit incorrect. I encourage you to read the `config.h` to learn more.

> why _FEATURES_H can be used to check if a header is the first included header

To be clear, "first" in the error message probably means "before this header". It works because of how header guards are used.